# Sort the dataframe by months after groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a sample of my data:

```
   Date        Count
11.01.2019       1  
01.02.2019       7  
25.01.2019       4  
23.01.2019       4  
16.03.2019       1  
04.02.2019       5
06.04.2019       1  
04.04.2019       5
```

Required output:

```
Month  Total_Count
Jan        9
Feb       12
Mar        1
Apr        6
```

I have used the following code, for the above operation of summing up, and it works fine, but the months are all jumbled up and not sorted accordingly like Jan,Feb

```
(df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
   .dt.month_name()
   .str[:3])['Count']
   .sum()
   .rename_axis('Month')
   .reset_index(name='Total_Count'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea is convert column to datetimes, then sorting and grouping with `sort=False` for avoid default sort in `groupby`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
df1 = (df.sort_values('Date')
         .groupby(df['Date'].dt.month_name().str[:3], sort=False)['Count']
         .sum()
         .rename_axis('Month')
         .reset_index(name='Total_Count'))
print (df1)
  Month  Total_Count
0   Jan            9
1   Feb           12
2   Mar            1
3   Apr            6
```

Another idea, thank you anky is use ordered `Categorical`s, then is necessary remove `sort=False`:

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

df1 = (df.groupby(pd.Categorical(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
         .dt.month_name().str[:3],ordered=True,categories=months))['Count']
         .sum()
         .rename_axis('Month')
         .reset_index(name='Total_Count'))
```

Or using [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

df1 = (df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
         .dt.month_name().str[:3])['Count']
         .sum()
         .rename_axis('Month')
         .reindex(months, fill_value=0)
         .reset_index(name='Total_Count'))

print (df1)
   Month  Total_Count
0    Jan            9
1    Feb           12
2    Mar            1
3    Apr            6
4    May            0
5    Jun            0
6    Jul            0
7    Aug            0
8    Sep            0
9    Oct            0
10   Nov            0
11   Dec            0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_df = (df.sort_values('Date')
     .groupby(df['Date'].dt.month_name().str[:3], sort=False)['Count']
     .sum()
     .rename_axis('Month')
     .reset_index(name='Total_Count'))
print(new_df)
```

Comment: Test it with data of OP.